# A vector of unique_ptr at specific positions in vector

Tags: c++, c++11, wxwidgets

I have a class called Grid which is composed of Cells. Each cell can have its own format (the concept is similar to MS Excel).

The format in the Grid is kept in a vector `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<CellFormat>> m_CellFormatTable` which owns all the formatting, so whenever I need to read a Cells format, I read it from the vector and whenever there is a change, it is reported back to the vector. Sorry, I am quite new to C++11 standards so my thinking might be wrong.

Since a grid is a matrix and each cell belongs to a different part of the matrix when there is a change in a cell's format it should be reflected in the correct part of the matrix, namely positioned correctly in the vector (CellFormatTable). Therefore, at this stage I cannot use the `push_back` method of the vector.

The CellFormat class:

```
struct CellFormat
{
    wxFont m_Font;
    wxColor m_BackgroundColor, m_TextColor;
    int m_HorizontalAlignment, m_VerticalAlignment;

    CellFormat(Grid* ws) {
        m_BackgroundColor = ws->GetDefaultCellBackgroundColour();
        m_TextColor=ws->GetDefaultCellTextColour();
        int horizontal = 0, vertical = 0;
        ws->GetDefaultCellAlignment(&horizontal, &vertical);
    }

    CellFormat(const CellFormat& other) {
        m_Font = other.m_Font;
        m_BackgroundColor = other.m_BackgroundColor;
        m_TextColor = other.m_TextColor;
        m_HorizontalAlignment = other.m_HorizontalAlignment;
        m_VerticalAlignment = other.m_VerticalAlignment;
    }

    CellFormat& operator=(const CellFormat& other) {
        if (this == &other) return *this;
        m_Font = other.m_Font;
        m_BackgroundColor = other.m_BackgroundColor;
        m_TextColor = other.m_TextColor;
        m_HorizontalAlignment = other.m_HorizontalAlignment;
        m_VerticalAlignment = other.m_VerticalAlignment;

        return *this;
    }
};
```

In the Grid.h

```
class Grid{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<CellFormat>> m_CellFormatTable;
    //
    CellFormat* GetCellFormat(int row, int column);
    void SetCellFormat(int row, int column, CellFormat format);
    void ApplyCellFormat(int row, int column, const CellFormat* format);
    CellFormat* CreateCellFormat(int row, int column);
    //rest is omitted
}
```

In Grid.cpp

```
Grid(some arguments){
    m_CellFormatTable.resize(nrows*ncols);
    //rest is omitted
}

CellFormat* Grid::GetCellFormat(int row, int column)
{
    int ncols= GetNumberCols();

    return m_CellFormatTable[row*ncols+ column].get();
}

void Grid::SetCellFormat(int row, int column, CellFormat other)
{
    CellFormat* format = GetCellFormat(row, column);
    if (format == 0) format = CreateCellFormat(row, column);
    *format = other;
}

void Grid::ApplyCellFormat(int row, int column, const CellFormat * format)
{
    if (format == 0) {
        int ncols= GetNumberCols();
        //Set everything to default values
        //Omitted

        m_CellFormatTable[row*ncols+ column].reset();
    }
    else {
        wxColor bgcolor = format->m_BackgroundColor;
        if (bgcolor.IsOk()) SetCellBackgroundColour(row, column, bgcolor);
        SetCellTextColour(row, column, format->m_TextColor);
        SetCellFont(row, column, format->m_Font);
        SetCellAlignment(row, column, format->m_HorizontalAlignment, format->m_VerticalAlignment);
    }
}

CellFormat* Grid::CreateCellFormat(int row, int column)
{
    int ncols= GetNumberCols();
    CellFormat* format = new CellFormat(this);
    m_CellFormatTable.emplace(m_CellFormatTable.begin() + row*ncols+ column, std::move(format));

    return format;
}
```

Whenever I format a cell, say its background color is changed, I use the following attempt:

```
CellFormat* format = ws->GetCellFormat(row, col);
if (format == 0) format = ws->CreateCellFormat(row, col);

if (ChangeFillColor) {
    ws->SetCellBackgroundColour(row, col, m_LastChosenFillColor);
    format->m_BackgroundColor = m_LastChosenFillColor;
}
```

The code fails at `ApplyCellFormat` function at the point of `format->m_BackgroundColor` since the color which should have been Cell's background color is not valid. This tells me that most and highly likely `CreateCellFormat` does not place CellFormat in the right location. I try to use `insert` rather than `emplace` but compiler (VS 2015) complained all my attempts.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Try to boil all this wall of code down to the essence of your question. What is not clear, is whether the matrix is supposed to be full (i.e. all valid pairs `i,j` are occupied by a cell or not).

Comment: @macroland, Why do you use your own grid and table class? wxWidgets already have all this including custom made grid table possibility...

Comment: Please post solutions as answers not as updates to your question. This is to help future visitors and to avoid confusion. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems.

 One is that you add a `CellFormat*` but your vector stores `unique_ptr` ;so you need `std::make_unique`with the new format.

Question: are you sure you need a vector of pointers instead of objects?

Other is that you presume the vector to have all data for all cells, being `0` if they are not set yet. That's wrong. The vector only have as many elements as you have 'pushed' or 'emplaced'.

Let's say you have 'pushed' the format for cell (0,0). Now you want to set the format for (5,2) which is (say you have 10 cols) the 52th element in the vector, but you have only one. So `vector[51]` is undefined (`vector.at(51)` will raise an error).

Add all cell formats first, with some value = 0 to tell it has not been set yet. Or re-think your strategy.

By the way, you can use [wxGridCellAttr](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_grid_cell_attr.html) which provides what you are coding on your own.

Comment: So you think even if my `get` method tries to retrieve the 52nd element which was supposedly placed there using `emplace` there will be an error since there is only one element in the vector?

Answer (score 1):

From the fact that you use a `vector` of `unique_ptr` (rather than of objects), I deduce that not all elements of the matrix are actually occupied. In this case, it may be better to use a `std::map` (or `std::unordered_map` if the matrix is very large) of objects (not `unique_ptr`s).

```
template<typename T>
struct grid
{
    using index = std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>;

    // insert element if not already present
    // returns if insertion occurred
    template<typename...Args>
    bool insert(index const&i, Args&&...args)
    {
        return data.emplace(std::forward<Args>(args)...).second;
    }

    // remove element (if it exists)
    void remove(index const&i)
    {
        data.erase(i);
    }

    // get pointer to element, may be nullptr
    T* get(index const&i)
    {
        auto it = data.find(i);
        return it==data.end() ?
            nullptr : std::addressof(*it);
    }
  private:
    std::map<index,T> data;
};
```

Comment: As a matter of fact you are right, not all cells are formatted (except the default format), therefore not all elements of the matrix are actually occupied. I will try this approach.

Answer (score 0):

The reason I see that your code is failing in this section of your code:

> ```
> CellFormat* format = ws->GetCellFormat(row, col);
> if (format == 0) format = ws->CreateCellFormat(row, col);
>
> if (ChangeFillColor) {
>     ws->SetCellBackgroundColour(row, col, m_LastChosenFillColor);
>     format->m_BackgroundColor = m_LastChosenFillColor;
> }
> ```

Is due to how your class is defined:

> ```
> class Grid{
>     std::vector<std::unique_ptr<CellFormat>> m_CellFormatTable;
>     //
>     CellFormat* GetCellFormat(int row, int column);
>     void SetCellFormat(int row, int column, CellFormat format);
>     void ApplyCellFormat(int row, int column, const CellFormat* format);
>     CellFormat* CreateCellFormat(int row, int column);
>     //rest is omitted
> }
> ```

By Default your class has it's members and functions set as `private:`

Change your class to this:

```
class Grid {
public:
    typedef std::vector<std::unique_ptr<CellFormat>> Format;
private:
    Format m_CellFormatTable;

public:
    CellFormat* getCellFormat( int row, int column );
    void        setCellFormat( int row, int column, const CellFormat& format );
    void        applyCellFormat( int row, int column, const CellFormat& format );

   // Add This Function If Needed
   Format getCellFormatTable() const { return m_CellFormatTable; }
};
```

So your class's member functions are declared as `public:` Then outside and non-friend objects can now have access to this class's member functions and be able to return the data structure via a get method.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for helpful comments and posts. Finally it works as expected.

As Ripi2 suggested, `CellFormat` objects in the vector were not initialized, so in the constructor I initialized them. Also not presented here, I had somewhere in the code a vector of objects not initialized, so corrected that part as well.

Although looping through all the rows and columns of the grid and creating a default format is NOT the best idea, a future work for me will be Walter's suggestion, i.e. to use sets.

```
Grid(some arguments){
    for (int i = 0; i < nrows*ncols; i++) {
        m_CellFormatTable.emplace_back(new CellFormat(this));
    }
   //Rest is omitted
}
```

Also corrected below code as well:

```
CellFormat* Grid::CreateCellFormat(int row, int column)
{
    int ncols = GetNumberCols();
    CellFormat* format = new CellFormat(this);
    std::unique_ptr<CellFormat> ptr(format);
    m_CellFormatTable.emplace(m_CellFormatTable.begin() + row*ncols + column,std::move(ptr));

    return format;
}
```

One way to keep track of formatting is:

```
CellFormat* format = ws->GetCellFormat(i, j);
if (ChangeFillColor) {
    ws->SetCellBackgroundColour(i, j, m_LastChosenFillColor);
    format->m_BackgroundColor = m_LastChosenFillColor;
}
```

Comment: you should consider using wxGridCellAttr with wxGrid as accepted answer suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and I would have considered using wxGridCellAttr but I am using the `m_CellFormatTable` at some other functions and so far made things easy to handle for me.